Код не дорабатывает указанные задачи до конца
Имеется следующий код на Python. Это код бота, и задачи этого кода следующие:
Код создает стол, а также вставляет карты на изображение. Карты генерируются перед наложением на стол.
Вся проблема заключается в том, что код генерирует 10 карт, но при этом первый цикл генерации он обрабатывает некорректно, и может упустить несколько карт. Как это исправить?
    q = 0
    tables = []
    while q < 2:
        # Размеры игрального стола
        table_width = 1280
        table_height = 720

        # Размеры карт
        card_width = 179
        card_height = 250

        # Создаем изображение игрального стола
        table_image = Image.open("Pictures/stol.png")

        # Загружаем изображения карт
        cards6 = ['6c', '6b', '6k', '6p']
        cards7 = ['7c', '7b', '7k', '7p']
        cards8 = ['8c', '8b', '8k', '8p']
        cards9 = ['9c', '9b', '9k', '9p']
        cards10 = ['10c', '10b', '10k', '10p']
        cardsK = ['Kc', 'Kb', 'Kk', 'Kp']
        cardsQ = ['Qc', 'Qb', 'Qk', 'Qp']
        cardsJ = ['Jc', 'Jb', 'Jk', 'Jp']
        cardsA = ['Ac', 'Ab', 'Ak', 'Ap']
        cards = {"6": cards6, "7": cards7, "8": cards8, "9": cards9, "10": cards10, "K": cardsK, "Q": cardsQ, "J": cardsJ,
                 "A": cardsA}
        appcard = []
        c = 0
        print(list(cards))
        while c <= 11:
            ca = random.choice(list(cards))

            carst = random.choice(cards[ca])
            print(carst)
            c = c + 1
            appcard.append(carst)

        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        le = {}
        for i in appcard:
            le[i] = False
        tables.append([rnd, appcard, le])
        q = q + 1

    return tables

Функция вызывается один раз.

Непонятно, что вы имели в виду, приведите какие-то примеры, что на выходе получается. А вообще основная проблема с таким выбором та, что вы можете одну и ту же карту выбрать несколько раз, у вас никак это не проверяется. В списке будет нужное число карт (но с повторами), а в словаре повторы невозможны, там будет недостаточное число карт. Используйте такие методы, которые сразу выбирают нужное число карт из всего набора.

При создании игры, бот вызывает асинхронную функцию Create21(), задача которой ТОЛЬКО создать словарь из карт, где ключ - это индекс карты, аля Kb - КорольБубны, и булево значение, отвечающее за проверку открытия карты. Create21() создает словарь из карт с дефолт False значением, оно никак не будет проверять карты и т.д., этим занимается иная функция, которая делает перебор карт из словаря, который ей достался от Create21. В самом цикле while, что находится по-середине, скрипт сначала делает перебор возможных карт из списка, и получив карту, рандомно выбирает её масть.

Код сверху и есть асинхронная Create21

Ваш метод, выбирающий карты из колоды по одной, может выбрать несколько раз одну и ту же карту. Вы не проверяете, что карта уже была выбрана. Далее, словарь не может содержать одинаковые элементы, поэтому в итоговом словаре будет меньше карт, чем нужно, если были повторы одной и той же карты.
Проще всего выбрать нужное количество карт из колоды за один присест, просто перетасовав предварительно колоду и выбрав сверху из неё нужное число карт.
Пример кода:
from random import shuffle

cards = [f'{n}{s}' for n in ['7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A'] for s in 'cbkp']
shuffle(cards)
choice = cards[:11]
print(choice)

Пример вывода (он случайный):
['Jb', 'Kb', '9b', 'Ap', '9k', 'Jp', 'Kp', 'Qc', '10c', '8p', 'Ab']

